# How to validate an array of Date with class validator?

Tags: api, nestjs, class-validator

I have an array of dates in a post request body that I want to validate:

```
{
    "meals": [...],
    "dates": [
        "2022-03-06T11:00:00.000Z",
        "2022-03-07T11:00:00.000Z"
    ]
}
```

This is my dto class:

```
export class CopyMealsPlanDto {
...// Another array

  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsDate()
  @Type(() => Date)
  dates: Date[];
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "dates must be a Date instance"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```js
export class CopyMealsPlanDto {
...// Another array

  @IsDateString({}, { each: true })
  dates: Date[];
}
```

You can read more about how to validate an array [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/454).

Answer (score 0):

You can use @IsDateString() decorator

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators

Comment: hi, if I use that, I'm getting this error: "dates must be a valid ISO 8601 date string"

Comment: @webber Because `@IsDateString` checking date type for ISO8601. Documentation says: "Alias for `@IsISO8601()`.". In your example date type is also ISO8601. Probably your data includes different type.